# Configuring for RichFaces: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter

Tags: jsf, richfaces, glassfish-3, web.xml

I have a project that contains some RichFaces components.
All other components get displayed but the RichFaces.

From the server logs I get:

*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter*

I am aware that with RichFaces 4.0 no filters are needed in the Web.xml.

Here is my **library**:

1. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
2. commons-collections-3.2.jar
3. commons-digester-1.8.jar
4. commons-digester.jar
5. commons-discovery.jar
6. commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
7. cssparser-0.9.5.jar
8. guava-r08.jar
9. jhighlight-1.0.jar
10. jsf-api.jar
11. jsf-facelets.jar
12. jsf-impl.jar
13. richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
14. richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar
15. richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
16. richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar
17. sac-1.3.jar

and this **my web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using GlassFish server 3.1.1

I have tried different configurations, also tried to include ajax4jsf.jar. But always ended up with the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

the complete server log is shown here:

```
0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WebModule[/HelloWorld_war_exploded]PWC1270: Exception starting filter richfaces
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove `jsf*.jar` from your libraries. The JSF 2.x libs are *already* provided by Glassfish3. Also, `jsf-facelets.jar` is of Facelets 1.x for JSF 1.x. The JSF 2.x libs already include Facelets 2.x.

As to the exception, just remove `<filter>` of `org.ajax4jsf.Filter` from `web.xml`. This is from RichFaces 3.x and not necessary anymore in RichFaces 4.x. Make sure that you're reading developer documentation for [RichFaces 4.x](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/) and **not** [RichFaces 3.x](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.I do not have any filters defined in Web.xml and removing jsf*.jar is creating other problems. Facelets components are OK in the project. The problem only is with the RichFaces they do not get displayed and I receive the server error mentioned previously.

Comment: Apparently the server is by itself corrupted due to improper presence of custom libraries and `web.xml`s. Try once again on a brand new and unmodified Glassfish install. Which "other problems" exactly are you talking about by the way? Please describe the symptoms and error messages in detail.

Comment: It is working now. I was using IntelliJ and if you choose GlassFish as the server it just loads three jars                            javax.ejb.jar
javax.servlet.jar             
javax.servlet.jsp.jar                                                  I switched to Netbeans and it is loading all the necessary libraries. Add to that I was using some tags that are not allowed anymore in RichFaces 4.0 and the IDE in netbeans was able to pick so everything is resolved now.

Comment: Great you solved it. I would however not expect IntelliJ to be that bad. Perhaps you should have set some configuration option during the project creation wizard that it's a JSF project? I don't use it, so I can't give a detailed answer on that.